# How to determine request is forwarded or not in java filters?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I need to log the request and response what user has requested. Currently am using filters and logging the request in doFilter() method. But if i forward the request from one servlet to another servlet it is logging twice. I need to find out the forwarded request and skip log for that. Could anyone suggest how to find the forwarded request.

Comment: Thanks Sergii, In that case i need to add this param in all the places where am forwarding request. I think it won't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `request.getDispatcherType()`. In case of direct request it's `request.getDispatcherType().name()` be REQUEST, in case of forward - FORWARD